# How to include an array as a parameter of an object in python?

Tags: python, arrays, object

So I know how to create objects in python with things like strings and numbers as parameters, but how would I include an array as one of the parameters of an object I want to create?

Comment: Could you add example of what you want?

Comment: The exact same way as any other parameter. Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Python doesn't have arrays as a standard datatype (they're a part of the Pandas module). Do you mean list?

Comment: `obj = myClass([1, 2, 3])` will pass the list `[1, 2, 3]` as the parameter to the class.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same process as with the all other attributes. Asign the attributes via `def __init__()` function and that's it. For example:

```
class EvenNumbers:
    def __init__(self, array):
        self.evenNumbers = array
```

Create an object:

```
array = [2, 6, 4] #NOTE: this structure is type list not array
en = EvenNumbers(array)
```

And then use it for whatever you need.